# same class validation , if one of the class are valid it post the form

Tags: javascript

```
// check validation function
function ListValidationFunction(event){
        //array validation function
        var Listvalidators = [peoplenameValidation];
        // bypass all function
        var Listvalid = Listvalidators.reduce(function(Listvalid, Listvalidator){
        return Listvalidator() && Listvalid;
         alert("true"); 
        }, true);

    return Listvalid;
}


// peoplename validation
function peoplenameValidation(){
var validationID = [];
var inputs = $('.people-name-input');

push all id to array
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
validationID.push(inputs[i].id);
}

if(validationID != ""){
for(var v = 0; v < validationID.length; v++){
var IDvalue = $('#'+validationID[v]);
var IDdata = IDvalue.val();
if(IDdata.length != ""){
    IDvalue.css('border-color', '#dfe0e6');
**//problem here , if one of the same class are != "" it return true, i need all the same class != "" then return true.**
    return true;
}else{
    IDvalue.css('border-color', 'red');
    // IDvalue.focus();
}
}
}
return false;
}
```

i had multiple same class input '.people-name-input' to validation,i check all input length and then push all they id to array then check it.

listValidationFunction is to check if peoplenameValidation return true and if do 
, post the form.

At peoplenameValidation return true , if one of the same class return true , the form will submit , how to i check if all the same calss are not empty then return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IDdata.length != ""` is going to be checked for every iteration of the loop, and `return` will break the loop (and the function). So don't exit the function inside the loop, if you need to check every iteration.

You can add a counter and increment it if `ID.data.length != ""`. Then after the loop, check if increment is equal to `validationID.length`, and `return true;` if it is.

Comment: haha it work , well explain why i never think of that. thank you.

Comment: I don't know why you never thought of that, but you are welcome :)